Speaker and Microphone not working on ThinkPad E14
I have a few students using ThinkPad E14, where both the mic and speakers are not functioning. Most of them are using Ubuntu 20.04. But on one student's laptop, I reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04, but the problem still persists.
The image below shows the screenshot of the top menu. Notice the earphone symbol, but no earphones are plugged in.
Can someone please help me with this? I have been trying since many days, but without any success.

